# I'm having this Error:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I'm having This Problem....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.nacxo.darshansoni.team_prediction.HalaplayMatches.onCreate(HalaplayMatches.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6974)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3012) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1716) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

This Is My `Halaplaymatches` Class:

```
public class HalaplayMatches extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private String name;
    TextView descriptionhala,e_advicehala,visit;
    ImageView imageView,imageView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_halaplay_matches);

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        name = bundle.getString("title");

        visit=findViewById(R.id.hmustVisit);
       // e_advicehala=findViewById(R.id.advicehalaplay);
        descriptionhala=findViewById(R.id.deschalaplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like it this.Before assigning value to name check whether bundle contains your key "title"

```
 if (getIntent() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (bundle.containsKey("title")) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(bundle.getString("title")) && bundle.getString("title") != "")
                        name = bundle.getString("title");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.. But I'm Having The Same error

Comment: I have edited my answer.Please try with this condition and let me know.

Comment: Now there is an error for ContainsKey : Null object refrence

Comment: And i've another 3 activities like this with the same code just change some key
And There were same error but i'm getting my data using key
And here it is not happenig

Comment: in that case just check if you are receiving anything in your bundle extras.

Comment: yes i've received my title
actually i'm receiving my title here as well But when i'm trying to get data from the title through jsonarray nd jsonobject nd volley also at that time it gives me nothing...
So then i debug that activity nd then it shows me this error
then i check my other activity but there were also same error but it gives me data whatever i want

Comment: Thank you It's solve but it gives me null insted of my title

Comment: this is because you might not be storing extras in "title" as a key

Comment: umm i'm not getting this sorry

Comment: from where are you calling "Halaplaymatches" class

Comment: from Halaplay.java

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a method on an object means to call a method that is on that object; for example, `"Hello World".length()` invokes the `length` method on the `String` with value `"Hello World"`.

As the error message says, `bundle` must be `null` on the line `name = bundle.getString("title");`, assuming that's line 56.

If you check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()), this happens when no extras have been added to the intent with `putExtras()`.

Comment: No i've added putExtras()
Here is the code: 
 Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),HalaplayMatches.class); 
 intent.putExtra("title",name.get(position).trim());
 startActivity(intent);

Comment: I know what the Java message means; I was just reading the documentation for how that's relevant to your problem. I don't know why `putExtra` wouldn't work in this case, but I'd still bet if you explicitly checked if `bundle` was `null`, you'd find it was.

Comment: yes i checked it for many times it's not null it gives me my title which i want
but when i'm trying to get my data through my title then it shows me blank activity in app....
i have another 2 activities with the same code just changes in the title or key
and there i'm getting my data but yes it's shows me an error like this while i debug my app

Comment: i don't know what happen to it
i did it for many times but now it doesn't working